# Expectation of sum of independent random variable

Tags: expectation

Let, for $m\neq 1$, $X_1, X_2\ldots$ be independent random variables with $E(X_n) = m^n, n \ge 1$, let $N \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ be independent of $X_1, X_2\ldots$ and set
$$Z = X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_N$$
Determine $E(Z)$.

It is trickier than the i.i.d.condition.

Please show me how can I solve it.

I'm sorry that I don't know the rule here, I'll add my work back then.

There is a theorem that E[Sn] = E[N]E[x], but it does not work here, because Xi are not i.i.d. I try to do some modification based on the theorem, but it seems hard for me to work it out.

Comment: This site works best when you show what you've done to try to solve the problem yourself. Can you please edit your post to show what you've tried?

Answer (score 4):

You have that:
$$\begin{align*}E[Z]&=E[X_1+\ldots+X_N]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E[X_1+\ldots+X_N |N=n]P(N=n)=\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(m^1+\ldots+m^n\right)e^{-\lambda}\cdot\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}=m\cdot e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}m^k\end{align*}$$ where from the geometric series $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}m^k=\frac{1-m^n}{1-m}$$ So $$\begin{align*}E[Z]&=m\cdot e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}m^k=me^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\frac{1-m^n}{1-m}=\frac{me^{-\lambda}}{1-m}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(m\lambda)^n}{n!}\right)=\\&=\frac{me^{-\lambda}}{1-m}\cdot (e^{\lambda}-e^{m\lambda})=\frac{m}{1-m}\cdot(1-e^{(m-1)\lambda})=\frac{m}{m-1}\left(e^{\lambda(m-1)}-1\right)\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks, It's a good idea to me. But the correct answer is [m/(m-1)][exp(λ(m-1))-1] and I don't know where is the mistake. - -

Comment: I found it!! The sums are equal to exp(λ) and exp(mλ) respectively and not exp(-λ) and exp(-mλ) as I had it! The minus sign was the mistake, I corrected it!